# Multiple radio button forms, single groups, can't retrieve values

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have been scouring the net for an answer to this, and have not found anything useful. I'm programming a quiz on a single web-page. I have not one form with multiple radio button groups, but multiple forms, each with their own radio button group.

Every time I run my code to grab the values from each form, I get no further than the first group; thereafter, the second iteration of my function call says my variable for the form fields is undefined.

Example of calls to form value retrieval code:

```
function submit_quiz(){
 var one, two, three;
 one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans1"), "a1");
 alert(one);
 one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans2"), "a2");
 alert(two);
 one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans3"), "a3");
 alert(three);
}
function getRadioValue(form, name){
 var val;
 var i;

 var f = form;
 var n = name;

 radios = f.elements[n];
 len = radios.length;

 for(i=0; i<len; i++){
  if(radios[i].checked){
    val = radios[i].value;
    break;
  }
 }
 return val;
}
```

Example of code for forms and radio buttons:

```
<ol class="quiz_question">
  <li id="q1">
    <p>According to Sun Tzu, the study of war is what to the state?</p>
    <form class="answer_selections" id="ans1">
    <input name="a1" value="1" type="radio" />A useless endeavor to be avoided.<br />
    <input name="a1" value="2" type="radio" />Too costly to be of any practical use.<br />
    <input name="a1" value="3" type="radio" />A matter of life and death.<br />
    <input name="a1" value="4" type="radio" />Important to the state's wealth.<br />
    </form>
  </li>
  <li id="q2">
    <p>Sun Tzu says long wars have what effect?</p>
    <form class="answer_selections" id="ans2">
    <input name="a2" value="1" type="radio" />Both the state's wealth, and the army's strength wane.<br />
    <input name="a2" value="2" type="radio" />Then enemy's strenght is steadily ground into nothing.<br />
    <input name="a2" value="3" type="radio" />Both sides will eventually choose a mutually agreable peace.<br />
    <input name="a2" value="4" type="radio" />There will be no effect as the war will become a stalemate.<br />
    </form>
  </li>
  <li id="q3">
    <p>If your army is five times as big as your enemies, what is your best course of action?</p>
    <form class="answer_selections" id="ans3">
    <input name="a3" value="1" type="radio" />Attempt to surround and destroy the enemy's forces.<br />
    <input name="a3" value="2" type="radio" />Pull back, and wait for a better opportunity to attack.<br />
    <input name="a3" value="3" type="radio" />Split your forces in two, and send one to attack the enemy's rear.<br />
    <input name="a3" value="4" type="radio" />Attack immediatly, unless the enemy holds some other serious advantage.<br />
    </form>
  </li>
```

Comment: `two/three` is declared as `undefined` and their value is not set anywhere..

Answer (score 2):

Could not find the button to submit the quiz. So have to add a button and attach listener `onclick` to it.

Also there is no need of passing the form `id`, Since the the name of radio buttons are different, `document.getElementsByName` can be use to get radio button of that name. Then loop by the node list to find the checked button.

Also in your function `submit_quiz` you are alerting `two` & `three` variable,but they are actually undefined.

```
var one, two, three; //Declared variable
 one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans1"), "a1"); // Assigned to one
 alert(one);
//Assigned to one again but not two
     one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans2"), "a2");
     alert(two); // alerting two but two in unassinged
   // Assigned to one again ,but alerting three
     one = getRadioValue(document.getElementById("ans3"), "a3");
     alert(three); //three is unassigned

document.getElementById("submitQuiz").onclick =function(){
 submit_quiz();
}

function submit_quiz(){
 var one, two, three;
 one = getRadioValue("a1");
 alert(one);
 two = getRadioValue("a2");
 alert(two);
 three = getRadioValue("a3");
 alert(three);
}



function getRadioValue(name){
var val =""
var _getCheckedRadio = document.getElementsByName(name);
for(var i =0;i<_getCheckedRadio.length;i++){
 if (_getCheckedRadio[i].checked ){
  val = _getCheckedRadio[i].value;
 }
}
 return val;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/j0fx2gsr/1/)

Comment: Apparently I was more tired than I thought when I coded this. It was just the simple mistakes you pointed out (feel dumb about missing them). Thanks a bunch. Now I can have everything fixed and turned in on time.